# How do you compact a Realm DB on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'd like to compact a Realm instance on iOS periodically to recover space. I think the process is to copy the db to a temporary location, then copy it back and use the new default.realm file.

My problem is `Realm()` acts like a singleton and recycles objects so I can't really close it and tell it to open the new default.realm file.

The docs here (https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html) suggest I wrap all the Realm() calls in `autorelease { }` but it can't be this complicated.

Answer (score 22):

It can be indeed tricky to completely tear down all retrieved model accessors, but there is unfortunately no other way to close a Realm.

As you wrote "periodically" every app launch might be often enough, depending on your use case.

On the launch of your application, it should be still relatively easy to open Realm in a dedicated autoreleasepool, write a compacted copy to a different path and replace your default.realm file with it.

#### Swift 2.1

```
func compactRealm() {
    let defaultURL = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!
    let defaultParentURL = defaultURL.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!
    let compactedURL = defaultParentURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("default-compact.realm")

    autoreleasepool {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        realm.writeCopyToPath(compactedURL)
    }
    try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(defaultURL)
    try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().moveItemAtURL(compactedURL, toURL: defaultURL)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    compactRealm()

    // further setup …

    return true
}
```

#### Swift 3.0

```
func compactRealm() {
    let defaultURL = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!
    let defaultParentURL = defaultURL.deletingLastPathComponent()
    let compactedURL = defaultParentURL.appendingPathComponent("default-compact.realm")

    autoreleasepool {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.writeCopy(toFile: compactedURL)
    }
    try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at: defaultURL)
    try! FileManager.default.moveItem(at: compactedURL, to: defaultURL)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    compactRealm()

    // further setup …

    return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you! the autoreleasepool was the key. I had everything else, but I was getting a crash without it. Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @marius what if Realm() throws exception and cant initialize realm because of big file size (ex. 3GB) ? Is there another way for compacting?

Comment: Hey @suleymancalik, sorry for the late reply. There isn't quite a way to compact in that case, but at the same time it should be really hard to get into this situation into the first place. So I wonder why you worry about this / how you got into that?

Comment: This was super helpful. Thanks, @marius.

Comment: Make sure you use the tweaked version suggested by @adam12 elsewhere on this page. The calls to removeItem() and moveItem() must occur outside the autorelease pool to ensure the realm object was deallocated.

Comment: @EliBurke: Thanks for your suggestion. I edited my answer to reflect that in the code.

Comment: Hi @marius Calling this on DidFinish launch will delay the app launch time.

Answer (score 8):

The answer given by @marius has an issue: the open Realm might still reference the deleted file. This means some writes might end up in the old (deleted) file, causing the app to lose data.

The correct implementation of compactRealm method looks like this (swift 3):

```
func compactRealm() {
    let defaultURL = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!
    let defaultParentURL = defaultURL.deletingLastPathComponent()
    let compactedURL = defaultParentURL.appendingPathComponent("default-compact.realm")

    autoreleasepool {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.writeCopy(toFile: compactedURL)
    }
    try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at: defaultURL)
    try! FileManager.default.moveItem(at: compactedURL, to: defaultURL)
}
```

This issue has been driving me crazy until I found an answer [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4766)

Answer (score 3):

Well.. it appears as though this issue is mostly obsolete. Realm added an automatic compact feature last fall. [Realm Docs / compacting-realms](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#compacting-realms). I think the only reason to do it as described by @marius is if you need to control the user experience and compact in the background.

See this question for more: [How to correctly use shouldCompactOnLaunch in RealmSwift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407812/how-to-correctly-use-shouldcompactonlaunch-in-realmswift)