# Realm database performance

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm trying to use this database with react-native. First of all, i've found out that it can't retrieve plain objects - i have to retrieve all of the properties in the desired object tree recursively. And it takes about a second per object (~50 numeric props). Slow-ish!

Now, i've somehow imported ~9000 objects in it (each up to 1000 chars including titles). Looks like there is no easy ay to import it, at least it is not described in docs. Anyway, that's acceptable. But now i've found out that my database size (`default.realm`) is 3.49GB (!). The JSON file, which i was importing is only 6.5mb. I've opened `default.realm` with [Realm Browser](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/realm-browser/id1007457278?mt=12) and it shows only those ~9000 objects, nothing else. Why so heavy?

Either, i don't understand something very fundamental about this database or it is complete garbage. I really hope i'm wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This forum is to answer specific coding questions so can you update your question with a code sample? We would need to know what is meant by 'plain objects' and 'retrieve... recursively'. Until then, this should be closed as it's too vague for us to really help.

Comment: About your issue for the excessive database size, is seems a known issue. You can check out this previous question for any possible solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865711/realm-file-size-is-too-large

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are not running in chrome debug mode. This is probably why things seem so slow. As far as the file size issue goes, it would be helpful if you posted your code to help figure out why that is happening.